# NSURLConnection not calling methods (worked the first time)

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsurlconnection

So I'm using an `NSURLConnection` to get JSON data from a website, it works and I store the data in a search controller/ table view. Now when a user clicks on a cell in the view I want to segue to a new view, and load another set of JSON data from a website. However, in this new view the connection never runs the methods. Here is what I'm doing both times (each in a different view controller)

```
func startConnection(){
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: self.formatted)!
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
    connection.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode) // I tried to put this in based on suggestions from searches I did, it didn't help
    connection.start()
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
    self.data.appendData(data)

}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!){
    var err: NSError
    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
    println(jsonResult)

}
```

From breakpoints it looks like it never runs:

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!)
```

I'm calling `startConnection()` in `ViewDidLoad`

Comment: @Rob Thanks, I wasn't sure how to accept answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [`connection:didFailWithError:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection:didFailWithError:), too. See what it reports. Without that, you have no way of knowing why it failed.

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    println("connection error = \(error)")
}
```

Also, in `didReceiveData` (and the rest of these methods), the `NSURLConnection` parameter is not optional. Back before these were audited, they may have used implicitly unwrapped optionals, but no longer. Double check your method signatures. If you actually define your class as explicitly conforming to `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` and `NSURLConnectionDelegate`, you should get warnings about this.

---

As an aside, you are not using the `NSError` variable in `connectionDidFinishLoading` that could be populated if `JSONObjectWithData` encountered any problems parsing the response. So supply that `NSError` variable to `JSONObjectWithData`, and you can now diagnose any errors that occur during the parsing. Hopefully you will not have any parsing errors, but if you do, having the `NSError` reference would be very useful.

Also, you don't need that `startImmediately` of `false` and manually scheduling it on the main run loop. You only do that if you are initiating this connection from a background thread. But since you're calling this from `viewDidLoad`, that's unnecessary.

So it might end up looking like:

```
func startConnection() {
    data = NSMutableData()
    let url = NSURL(string: formatted)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
    self.data.appendData(data)
}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection) {
    var error: NSError?
    if let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &error) as? NSDictionary {
        println(jsonResult)
    } else {
        println("parsing error = \(error)")
        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    println("connection error = \(error)")
}
```

By the way, you might also want to implement `didReceiveResponse` as that can also provide information about any server errors you may receive:

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse) {
    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if statusCode != 200 {
            println("expected HTTP response of 200; received \(statusCode)")
            println(httpResponse)
        }
    } else {
        println("expected HTTP response; but didn't get any")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the printing errors really helped, I found out that the problem was an unsupported url error and I fixed it

Comment: @Chris Yeah, it had to be something like that. I'd suggest always availing yourself of whatever error reporting available. Makes our lives much easier!